# Problem in opening ASP.NET mvc 1 projects in ASP.NET mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I cannot open a project built on ASP.NET MVC 1 in an MVC 2 environment. I get an exception saying 'The Project File xxxx.csproj cannot be opened. This project type is not supported by this installation'. 
I can create a new MVC application though. I suspect this is due to the backward non compatibility of MVC 2 and 1, but am not sure. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can open MVC1 projects but you need to delete a key from the project file:

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/01/20/opening-an-asp-net-mvc-project-without-having-asp-net-mvc-installed-the-project-type-is-not-supported-by-this-installation.aspx

You can also upgrade them with this tool:

http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2009/10/19/migrating-asp-net-mvc-1-0-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MVC 2 is not seamlessly backward compatible.

You can have MVC 1 and MVC 2 installed side by side.

You can upgrade your MVC 1 project to MVC 2, see [upgrading information](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet-mvc2-upgrade-notes).